# Urban Airship typings and Ionic 2 integration

Tags: android, ios, typescript, ionic2, urbanairship.com

I am trying to integrate the Urban Airship push plugin into an Ionic2 application. So far all I managed is the installation of the plugin and I did manage to find typings for the api ([link to definitions](https://github.com/retyped/urbanairship-cordova-tsd-ambient)). However, the typings are not being recognized by the parser and I can find no support whatsoever on the matter. I keep getting a 'module not recognised' error. I can manage the initialisation of the plugin, but I'm currently stuck on the definitions part. Any support is more than appreciated.

Regards,
Alan

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: just moved to OneSignal :/